# Please explain the "Generalist" badge in simple terms

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

Ok, so I see a number of posts on this badge, but I can't get to the bottom of it.

As far as I understand it:

- The top 40 tags on a site need to have more than 200 questions each.
- Users need to gain at least 15 up-votes in 20 of those top 40 tags

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/632524/updated-generalist-progression) (and others I found very similar), I almost qualify for the badge (my user number is 10945) and I have just a few more votes in the "humans" tag to go.

I'm currently a middle-ranking user on WorldBuilding, so it's reasonable to assume that many other users have qualified in terms of the two points above.

For reference, [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags) is the list of tags on WB.

I also read Jeff Atwood's announcement of this badge on his [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/)

> One thing the badge doesn't say, is that there must be at least 200 questions in all 40 of the top tags before this badge is awarded to anyone. That's why you won't see it on meta for a bit longer, or any new sites for about a year. I don't feel you can accurately measure a generalist until the top tag list settles down

So, there's something simple here that I'm obviously missing and not been able to work out from the numerous other questions on this subject.

I agree that "If you don't understand it, you don't deserve it." is most probably a valid response here.

Comment: So the real problem here is down to Jeff Atwood saying "at least" when he really meant "over"....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Worldbuilding isn't *quite* there yet.

Each of the top 40 tags needs *over* 200 questions, not 200 exactly.

Currently, tags 39 and 40 have exactly 200 questions. When another `near future` question and another `cities` question are asked, the badges for WB should go out.

I know this from personal experience on MSO. I was confused why the badges didn't go out when the 40th tag finally got 200 questions. When the tag got one more question past that, the badges went out.

This is also listed as "over 200" on the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/266735) with a link to another user, in chat, who had been confused by the same thing. If you go back two days in the transcript for that room, you'll see they were asking if the tags needed >= 200 or > 200.

Comment: Many thanks, that was it exactly.  I tagged (appropriately) two questions and now the WB stack has 69 users awarded the Generalist badge.